# How to solve "Recv failure: Connection was reset" in apigee

Tags: curl, libcurl, apigee, oauth-2.0, apigee-baas

This is the error i got in my curl utility command prompt. please give a proper good solution to me.

Thank you.

and Please find the Attachment image of my error.

[image]

Comment: Did you use the trace tool to see whether the request made it to Apogee and/or if the target returned a more meaningful error?

Comment: yes, i did, but it shows the bad request error there ..@Michael Bissell

Comment: From where? I mean... is it coming from the target response? Or from Apigee itself?

Comment: It came from apigee itself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the apigee documentation for troubleshooting:

http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/content/troubleshooting

It sounds like the request is making it to Apigee, so it's not an issue with your local network or ability to run curl.  Then you can see if the error is being generated by one of your policy attachments or if it's coming from the target server.  A lot of times these errors aren't actually from Apigee but passed through from some resource Apgiee is brokering.

Comment: yah, I got you but some times the apigee formule are also not giving proper response to me. Means Access token is not generated properly and i got that "Recv: Connection reset" error.